# Using Youtube API to move videos to another media host

Tags: php, youtube, download, private

Can I make a PHP script, using Youtube API or any other legal way, to directly copy mp4 files from my own youtube channel to Amazon S3 or other media host?

I need this because my client wants me to make native iPhone / Android apps that will stream the videos from his channel.

I know I can do it manually from Youtube web, but the problem is that I can only download vids locally and then again upload to Amazon which seems like a waste of time and assets.